# Switch statement case duplicate error

Tags: android, switch-statement

I am getting an error on this switch statement called Duplicate case even though im not sure what the problem is, I have defined each case along with return value. I am using this for a dialog that I am using for the `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` layouts for android. Please let me know if I am defining the case statments incorrectly or if something else is wrong.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch(id)
    {

    case Time_dialog_id:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false);

    case Date_dialog_id:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: How do you declare the ids?

Comment: static final int Date_dialog_id = 0;
static final int Time_dialog_id = 0;

Comment: Well do you see anything odd there? You declare both ids to zero. Shouldn't they be separate values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem is because both **Date_dialog_id** and **Time_dialog_id** are initialized to **0**. give them different values.

```
static final int Time_dialog_id = 0;
static final int Date_dialog_id = 1; 

protected void test(int id){

    switch(id){
    case Time_dialog_id:
        Log.d("test()", "Time_dialog_id:");
        break;
    case Date_dialog_id:
        Log.d("test()", "Date_dialog_id:");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
switch(id)
{

case Time_dialog_id:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false);
break;

case Date_dialog_id:
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
break;
}
return null;

}
```

You forgot the "break;".I suppose this is what was bugging your code.

Comment: i added the break but it still gives me the same error of a duplicate case.

Comment: Would you please link the log? -nevermind, the log won't help me,I suppose.

 static final int Date_dialog_id = 0;
 static final int Time_dialog_id = 0;

This is how you declare them, would you please try to give the Time_dialog_id the value of 1, when declared?

 static final int Date_dialog_id = 0;
 static final int Time_dialog_id = 1; (Like this)

P.S:Sorry for the edits, can't get used to the fact that Return will post my comment.

Comment: hm interesting, when i declare the value to 1, it will ask me to remove `break` so when i do that, the code checks out with no errors.

Comment: umm it's weird that it asks you to remove break.

Practically if you remove the break, when the first case it's "true" ,the second case will be true also.So the whole functionality will go wrong,I suppose.

Comment: ok so i can only set one of the variables to 1 and it will run but if i try to use the method then, it will just crash.

Comment: Can you try something like storing the new TimePickerDialog / DatePickerDialog to a variable (for each,of course) and after that ,return the variable instead of returning "new bla bla"?

I am not sure if this will help but it might.

Also: using "this" as a parameter means you are in the activity of the app,right? (If ur not ,make sure you are)

And the last thing: Can you please give me the LogCat of the crash when you use the method?

Comment: also heres another odd thing, if i were to delete one of the cases along with both breaks. the method will work perfectly

Comment: Yea, it's something about the variables you are using within the switch statement or perhaps about the way you are using them.

I am way too tired at this moment,gotta get some sleep.If I get any decent ideas in the morning I will come back with an answer.But you should still try what I told you in the last comment.